# Why am i getting this exception in firebase crashlytics? IllegalStateException : UiAutomation not connected

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics, android-uiautomator

[image]I know that Google console runs Uiautomation tests(prelaunch).
However crash logs that i receive in firebase crashlytics do not seem to be related to the prelaunch process, because this exception happens in previous versions of our service.

Is this something related to hacking?? Ex) someone trying to hack our app by download our apk and running ui testings using adb commands?

Btw, about hundred logs were reported in short period of time.

I tried using adb commands and emulator to run our app’s ui testing to simulate the crash, however could not figure out.

Comment: Sometimes hacked apps may have a different package name, is this the case here?

Comment: @Gerardo Well, no different package name. is this related to some kind of a user trying to hack our app using ui testing?